# wpf datatable column name can not have slash /

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I'm very new to WPF.
I'm having a very weird issue to just make a table,
here is the code I have:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("request/sec", typeof(string));
DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
newRow["request/sec", "na");
```

but it only shows a column name with "request/sec" and an empty row

however, if I do:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("test(request/sec)", typeof(string));
DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
newRow["test(request/sec)", "na");
```

then it's working, it shows the column name correctly, and a row with value "na"

I have no idea why this is happening, I know it sounds ridiculously.
Can anyone help?

note: I also tried "//", "/", "\/", @
I can not hardcoded the column names, it's dynamic generated by certain logic, I used the above code as examples

Comment: Are you having the grid generate the columns, or are you specifying them yourself?  If you're doing it yourself, show us how you're doing it.  Also, what is the `ItemsSource` of the grid?

Comment: the column names are generated. :(

Answer (score 0):

[Data don't show up when bind ItemsSource of a WPF DataGrid to a DataTable which contains columns like '01/14/10' - MS WPF forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/111998d6-eb3e-420b-a357-1a0918ea9c0f/data-dont-show-up-when-bind-itemssource-of-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-datatable-which-contains-columns?forum=wpf) discusses this problem.

In brief, this was claimed to be a WPF Toolkit bug as of March 22, 2010 and refers to tickets reporting similar problems with some other characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues creating bindings when a property name contains some reserved characters like `.` and `/`.  The property path parser just doesn't handle them.  You have a couple options:

1. Instead of having the grid automatically generate the columns, define them yourself, and for columns with reserved characters, bind to the data row's indexer instead of the column name:

   ```
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[request/sec]}" Header="request/sec" />
   ```
2. If you only care about the column name because you want to control the column header text, just declare the columns manually, give the column a "legal" name, and set the `Header` just like above.

Comment: I need to generate the column name..it's not always the same. T_T

Comment: Could you remove illegal characters from the column name but keep them in the column header?  It would look the same to the user.  You can still generate the columns, but you can do it yourself instead of relying on the grid.

Comment: How do I remove illegal characters from the column name but keep them in the column header?

Comment: Generate the columns manually and assign the correct header to the `Header` property.

Comment: This is a DataGrid column, not a DataColumn :-(