# Datagrid does not show full Data of Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I'm loading a DataTable from a Database and but do not want to have it the way it looks. That’s why I decided to create a new DataTable and fill it with my received Data.
Unfortunately, the data are not fully shown in the DataGrid. To be more detailed, only the first column is shown but all other are not. While debugging I could ensure that the DataTable is filled correctly.

Does anyone of you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Model:

```
internal DataTable getValueTable(ObservableCollection<CheckableMenuitem> listSelectableValues)
{
    DataTable TableToReturn = new DataTable();

    string LaborValueColumnCaption = Properties.Resources.LabValueColumnCaption;
    TableToReturn.Columns.Add(LaborValueColumnCaption);

    List<string> selectedValueNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (CheckableMenuitem item in listSelectableValues.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true))
    {
        selectedValueNames.Add(item.Caption);
    }

    string selectionFormular = "Wertname in ('" + string.Join("', '", selectedValueNames) + "')";
    DataRow[] selectionRows = fullValueTable.Select(selectionFormular);

    HashSet<DateTime> ListOfDays = new HashSet<DateTime>();

    foreach (DataRow item in selectionRows)
    {
        DateTime? Tmp = Functions.ParseNullableDate(item["Messdatum"].ToString());
        if (Tmp != null)
        {
            ListOfDays.Add(((DateTime)Tmp).Date);
        }
    }

    string DateFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";

    foreach (DateTime date in ListOfDays)
    {
        TableToReturn.Columns.Add(date.ToString(DateFormatString));
    }


    foreach (var valueName in selectedValueNames)
    {
        string singleSelectionFormular = "Wertname ='" + valueName + "'";
        List<DataRow> singleSelectionRows = fullValueTable.Select(singleSelectionFormular).ToList();

        if (singleSelectionRows.Count() == 1)
        {
            DateTime? ValueDate = Functions.ParseNullableDate(singleSelectionRows[0]["Messdatum"].ToString());

            if (ValueDate != null)
            {

            }

            DataRow newRow = TableToReturn.NewRow();

            //erste Spalte
            newRow[LaborValueColumnCaption] = valueName;

            string spalte = ((DateTime)ValueDate).ToString(DateFormatString);

            newRow[spalte] = singleSelectionRows[0]["MESSWERT_ALPHA"].ToString();
            //newRow[((DateTime)ValueDate).ToString(DateFormatString)] = singleSelectionRows[0]["MESSWERT_ALPHA"].ToString();

            TableToReturn.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        if (singleSelectionRows.Count() > 1)
        {
            List<DataRow> Rows = new List<DataRow>() { TableToReturn.NewRow() };
            Rows[0][LaborValueColumnCaption] = valueName;

            HashSet<DateTime> usedDates = new HashSet<DateTime>();

            foreach (var item in singleSelectionRows)
            {
                DateTime? ValueDate = Functions.ParseNullableDate(singleSelectionRows[0]["Messdatum"].ToString());

                if (ValueDate != null)
                {
                    DateTime Date = ((DateTime)ValueDate).Date;

                    if (usedDates.Add(Date))
                    {
                        string name = "Wertname ='" + valueName + "' and Messdatum > " + Date + " and Messdatum < " + Date.AddDays(1);
                        DataRow[] test2 = fullValueTable.Select(singleSelectionFormular);
                        //Rows[0][((DateTime)ValueDate).ToString(DateFormatString)] = singleSelectionRows[0]["MESSWERT_ALPHA"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow newRow in Rows)
            {
                TableToReturn.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }
    }

    return TableToReturn;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public DataTable ValueTable
{
    get
    {
        return model.getValueTable(ListSelectableValues);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ValueTable}"/>
```

edit:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTEdj.png)

Comment: How many columns does the returned DataTable actually has? What column do you see? What if you bind to the DefaultView property of it; ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ValueTable.DefaultView}?

Comment: I don’t know how many columns there will be, it might always be different. But I did proof that and all columns are shown correctly, Only the Values are missing. I will update my post and give you a Screenshot. Binding the defaultView didn’t solve my problem. I even tried to return the DataView (.AsDataView()) in my ViewModel.

Comment: But how many are there at runtime when you run/debug your code...?

Comment: i checked it for 2,3,5 and 7 days, everytime the correct amount columns where created.

Comment: Well, please provide a reproducible sample then: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem lays on the date format:

[wpf datatable column name can not have slash /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537983/wpf-datatable-column-name-can-not-have-slash)

Cheers,

Marco